# Offline html5 web with ajax and manifest

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, html, manifest

I'm trying to make this website:

http://mda-network.com/stradivarius/magazine_5/en/revista.php

offline.

I'm using this manifest file:

http://mda-network.com/stradivarius/magazine_5/en/cache.appcache

but when I go offline I can't change page with left and right arrows. Browser shows and xmlhttprequest error. Exactly the one in this JQuery function of the website:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',               
            url: '../httpRequest/carga_pagina_json_en.php?avoidcahe=' + myTimestamp(),
            cache: false,
            data: {
                pag: pagina,
                otro: 'ooo',
                renew: myTimestamp()
            },
            dataType: 'json',                       // Tipo de parametros que devuelve el php

 //         contentType: 'application/json',        // Tipo de parametros que le enviamos al php. Si añadimos esta linea en el paso de parametros por json, entonces no funciona !!!                
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                    x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
                }
                    $("#main").attr(    'src', "../image_resources/blanca.jpg");
                    $("#preloader").fadeIn(1200);
            },  
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, quepaso, errorThrown){
            alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.statusText+"\nque paso="+quepaso+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown.text);
        },
```

It works fine online. 
I searched a lot but I have not find any solution. What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an **avoidcahe** query string parameter so the URL is different each time and can't come from the browser cache.

Comment: Thank you Maurice,
I've changed this:

url: '../httpRequest/carga_pagina_json_en.php?avoidcahe=' + myTimestamp(),

to this:

url: '../httpRequest/carga_pagina_json_en.php'/*?avoidcahe=' + myTimestamp()*/,

but the same error appears.

The webtool for Chrome, always shows that the file "carga_pagina_json_en.php" is not xharged from cache. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say offline, do you mean there's really no internet connection at all? If so, how is your browser supposed to make an AJAX request?

You might want to check out [jQuery Offline](https://github.com/wycats/jquery-offline). It caches your AJAX locally using localStorage, and falls back to the cached data if there's no connection. Might need a bit of tweaking to make this work with the images you are displaying though. You'll probably have to use `data:` URLs.

Comment: Yes, without internet connection. I thought that if I cached all files, the web will work always offline, from cache. But thank you, now I see that is not so simple. I will take a look at jquery offline link.

Comment: Basically the idea of Offline HTML is that you cache all your static files like CSS, JS and design images, and load content using AJAX, which is then cached locally. There are JS events for when the Browser goes on- or offline. You might also want to check out those tutorials: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/#offline and http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Comment: I need some help, please. I understand that I have to change the ajax function that I posted to $.retrieveJSON("../httpRequest/carga_pagina_json_en.php", function(json, status) { to work with JQuery Offline lib (I included it in index.html). Is this correct? Can you give me some tips to make the web offline. Thanks.

Comment: The php site that handles your AJAX requests *must not* be included in the Cache manifest, the jQuery Offline lib *must* be included. You then replace all AJAX requests with `$.retrieveJSON`. The returned JSON will automatically cached, and if the client is offline, the cached version will be used.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have time for a more detailed solution right now, if you haven't solved the problem by tonight, I'll include some sample code in my answer. You might want to check out http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Offline+Apps Even though you're not working with Rails, it will probably help you understand what's going on in the background.

Comment: ok, thank you very much. The tricky thing is that $.retrieveJSON doesn't accept succes like $.ajax